# Is there any library to track call time and sms time in android?

Tags: android

I want to a software to calculate call time and sms time usage in Android, 
anyone has idea about any build-in library which handle such things ????

any way I can extract call logs in Android???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the call usage data from the content provider [CallLog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html).

The following code should work:

```
Cursor c = null;
try {
    c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            int duration = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
            // do something with duration
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
```